# Spatial Indexing and Bounding Box

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, geospatial, spatial, spatial-index

I have two tables each with a **SHAPE** Geom Column, and I'm working on getting the intersected area between every shape in the first table with the second table.

The second table has millions of rows, and hence my query takes a long time to execute.
I thought of creating an index on the **SHAPE** Column using:

```
create spatial index SPIX_Shape on LAND_V1(Shape) using geometry_auto_grid
```

I'm getting the following error message:

> The CREATE SPATIAL INDEX statement is missing the required parameter 'BOUNDING_BOX'.
> Validate the statement against the index-creation syntax.

I'm new to the spatial data world, so correct me if I'm wrong here.
Initially, I thought that bounding box should be automatically created by the DB Engine, checking each individual shape Geom and creating a bounding box for that when indexing. How do I manually specify a bounding box for my data?

And will that bounding box then affect the intersected area I calculate at the end? Will it differ depending on the GeomType [Polygon/MultiPolygon/GeometryCollection etc..]?

Here's my query:

```
select          
                s1.*,
                s2.Shape.STIntersection(s1.Shape) as SHAPE
from   LAND_V1 s1
inner join LAND_V2 s2 -- biggerTable
ON s1.Shape.STIntersects(s2.Shape) = 1
```

How would I leverage spatial indexing here

Comment: “The Bounding Box”
Geometric data occupies a plane that can be infinite. In SQL Server, however, a spatial index requires a finite space. To establish a finite space for decomposition, the geometry grid tessellation scheme requires a rectangular bounding box. The bounding box is defined by four coordinates, (x-min,y-min) and (x-max,y-max)….Only operations computed on objects that are entirely inside of the bounding box benefit from the spatial index. Therefore, to gain the greatest advantage from a spatial index …you need to specify a bounding-box that contains all or most of the objects.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver16#the-bounding-box

Comment: Out of curiosity, do your data represent geographic entities? Based on the table names, I think the answer might be "yes". If so, the geography data type might be more appropriate. If you do that, you don't need to specify a bounding box on the index as a default one is implied (i.e. "the whole Earth").